# Less установка

Tags: javascript, less

Был скачен сам пакет на офф сайте, подключены все ссылки, как прописано в инструкции

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

но в результате прописанные стили в styles.less не отрабатывают браузере проект был создан в папке пакета , также я не нашёл в корне less.js и не могу понять в чем мина данного способа, как компилировать я понимаю но почему процесс подключения не проходит не понимаю

```
http://lesscss.org/
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте подключить less.js через cdn, как указано в документации.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.1/less.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="test"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/f5ZEmXZ8sybFvw9Q5SkS?p=preview)

Так же хотелось бы уточнить, про какой пакет идет речь, архив с github ? Если да, то less.js находится в dist